# Latest available Android OS version for different devices

Tags: android, updates

How to easily check for the latest available Android OS version for different devices like mobiles, tablets. This is for my project related acitivty. Let me know if there are any particular website or any other related links for getting this info. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello Raam. Try to make some Google search first... You can check the "on topics" for Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and how to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello guys, Sorry for an 'off-topic' question or maybe a question not put with the correct wordings. Anyway I got the info requested :) Thanks again for maintaining this wonderful knowledge repo and Q&A site. Sorry if I had spammed it in any way !!!

Comment: Btw, I did a lot of Google search before putting this question here. I guess I even landed into the same link as mentioned below to get that info, so I hope this will be a useful info to be here as well !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think There is no such specific site for getting such information but i usually get such information through blogs and different people who gives latest and greatest information. For example
https://www.androidpit.com/android-5-0-lollipop-phone-update-news

or like **Motorola has this site for update check**

https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/standalone/country-selector/software-upgrade

i think this type of site may be with different vendors so you can find the latest update they have got.

Comment: Thanks a lot Om, I also got hold of the first link, which was very useful. That was the info which I was looking for